# Propagation level for multiple transaction methods called from a non-transactional method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I was going through this article https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

I had a doubt regarding what happens when multiple `@Transactional` methods are called from a non-transactional method.

```java
ADao.java
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public A getA()

@Transactional
public A insertA()

AService.java
public void getAndInsertA() {
    aDao.getA();
    aDao.insertA();
}
```

Is my understanding correct when I say both these calls `getA()` and `insertA()` will be part of separate transactions?

Another question, is it possible that both the queries will use the same DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your queries are not in the same transaction. If you want to, annotate your service with @Transactional.

And maybe. You have a connection pool, you don't really know if your transactions will use the same connection. But that's not really important, is it ?

Comment: It is important because if both the operations use same connection, write query might end up in read only DB replica?